# How to hold large outputs in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Sometimes, commands generate large outputs in powershell, e.g. chocolatey help:

> choco -h

How do I limit (hold output) to read the content in smaller parts? I believe there is similar functionality on Linux terminal.

Comment: Have you tried piping it to More?

Comment: Try `Out-Host` with [paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host?view=powershell-7.1).

Answer (score 0):

```
choco -h | more
```

Press space to scroll down.